# If my i create new distribution certificate and update provision profile with that certificate will my APNS certificate will be affected?

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have created new distribution certificate from new mac and I have updated my provisioning profile with that certificate. So I want to know will my APNS certificate will be affected which is already used by a live app.

Comment: No APNS does not have any relation with the provisioning profile and the distribution certificate. It only binds with application bundle identifier.